# Password encnryption in Liquibase properties file

Tags: database-migration, liquibase

To manage migration with Liquibase, I am using a properties file that holds all the information about the database connection. The pitfall of this file is that it discloses my database password since it is a plain text file. Is there a way to avoid that ? Does Liquibase support any kind of encryption for the properties file ?

Comment: You could just edit the file to include the password when you're about to run an update, and edit it to remove the password afterwards.

Comment: I am including that as part of a project that I am working on, not quite sure if it is the best solution to manage migration using code. This might work if the migration execution is done manually once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this  jira: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1932
Looks like you may use your own property provider class to handle encryption etc. I haven't seen any docs for it, but you can browse commits for this task.